# python when string in line get data from next line

Tags: python, string

I need to get the data from the line that is below my match

example:

```
for line in file:
  if 'string' in line:
    doSomething(nextline)
```

I have tried a few different ways . I always get a traceback

Comment: a traceback that you've chosen not to include? :P

Comment: sry had been through many attempts.

Comment: include the error, include your attempt, include a mockup file

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file object, you could do:

```
for line in f:
    if SOMETEXT in line:
        foo(next(f))  # not next(line), next(f)
```

However this will cause your `for` loop to skip the next line. Instead you could iterate by two lines.

```
import itertools

with open(...) as f:
    a, b = itertools.tee(f)
    next(b)  # skips a line in the "next line" iterator
    for thisline, nextline in zip(a,b):
        if SOMETEXT in thisline:
            foo(nextline)
```

This is actually the `pairwise` recipe on the [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) page in the docs. Keep that link handy -- it's incredibly useful

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Comment: thank you very much this is very helpful

Comment: My out put is nothing .. am i doing something wrong . I know the string is in there

Comment: a, b = itertools.tee(log)
            next(b)
            for firstline, secondline in zip(a, b):
                if "[DETECTION]" in firstline:
                    print(secondline)

Comment: without knowing what's in `log`, it's hard to say what's gone wrong. You should try debugging it and seeing what's going on with your file. `print(firstline)` in the `for` loop or etc.